# Grab & print specific objects from a JSON array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The code below grabs & prints all arrays and their objects per a user's search query on SoundCloud.  I do not need every object to be displayed and thus I went ahead and added slice.  Though it's slicing the first few characters of the array, rather then grabbing the first few objects in each array.  Where have I gone wrong?

```js
function audioResults(){
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search, false);
 xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
     var listResults = xhr.response;
  var sliceResults = listResults.slice(0,9);
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = sliceResults;
 }, false);
 xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- JS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<input type="search" id="search" />

<button onclick="audioResults()">Search</button>

<p id="results"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listResults.slice(0,9)
```

This gets the first 9 characters of listResults. What you want is to parse the data.

```
JSON.parse(listResults);
```

Then you can use Array.prototype.slice on that.

```
JSON.parse(listResults).slice(0, 9);
```

To return it to its string form stringify it:

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(listResults).slice(0, 9));
```

Comment: Thanks! Though now with the code above and when a search is executed all I'm getting is [object, Object], [object, Object], [object, Object,] etc vs. something like "id": 13158665, "downloadable": true, "original_format": "m4a", etc....Thanks!  Though now with the co

Comment: @chaser7016 Oh, you can turn it back into regular text by JSON.stringify'ing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [parse the resulting JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var listResults = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
```

Using your example:

```js
function audioResults(){
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search, false);
 xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
            // parse JSON result
     var listResults = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
  var sliceResults = listResults.slice(0,9);
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = sliceResults;
 }, false);
 xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- JS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<input type="search" id="search" />

<button onclick="audioResults()">Search</button>

<p id="results"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Though now with the code above and when a search is executed all I'm getting is [object, Object], [object, Object], [object, Object,] etc vs. something like "id": 13158665, "downloadable": true, "original_format": "m4a", etc....

Comment: @chaser7016 That's because you're implicitly calling each of the objects' [.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method when you write the text to the screen. You may want to consider iterating over the `sliceResults` (via `.forEach` or similar) and printing specific properties of each returned object. You can better inspect the contents of those objects by doing `console.log(sliceResults);` and looking in your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the results using javascript, you have to first `JSON.parse` the results, *then* you can can `slice` it and finally `JSON.stringify` it to get a string as a result.

but, I would recommand you to filter the results at the API request level. take a look at the soundcloud [Pagination API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#pagination) you can add a `limit=10` parameter to the request URL (eg: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=Einsteins&limit=10 )

and if you want to access the following pages, there is the `linked_partitioning` parameters. if this parameter is `1`, the response array will be wrapped into on an object containing the `collection` (the tracks for the first page) and `next_href` (the link to the next page results) eg: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=Einsteins&limit=1&linked_partitioning=1

Answer (score 0):

When you slice the resulting XHR JSON string it is takes the first 9 characters or objects starting at 0.

Which property of the object is the user searching on?

You can grab the target property that you want to search by then performing a loop base on that.

This should work.

```
function audioResults(){
    var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
         var dataLength = listResults.length;
         for ( var ii = 0; dataLength  >= ii; ii++ ) {
             var title = listResults[ii].title;
             if (title.indexOf(search) > -1) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = listResults[ii].title + '<br />' + listResults[ii].genre title+ '<br />' + listResults[ii].description;
             }
        }Y
    }, false);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and got it working using a for loop...

```js
    function audioResults() {
        var search = document.getElementById("search").value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=1dff55bf515582dc759594dac5ba46e9&q=" + search, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
            // parse JSON result
            var listResults = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            var sliceResults = listResults.slice(0, 9);
            console.log(sliceResults);
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = '';
            for (var x in sliceResults) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += '<a href="' + sliceResults[x].user.permalink_url + '">';
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += '<img src="' + sliceResults[x].user.avatar_url + '" />';
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += '<strong>' + sliceResults[x].user.username + '</strong>';
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += '</a>';
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += '<p><a href="' + sliceResults[x].permalink_url + '">' + sliceResults[x].title + "</a></p>";
            }
        }, false);
        xhr.send();
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- JS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

<input type="search" id="search" />

<button onclick="audioResults()">Search</button>

<p id="results"></p>


</body>
</html>
```